# Angular 2 Loop of Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to do the following in Angular 2:

1. Fetch data (using Observable)
2. Validate data.
3. IF valid THEN return data ELSE goto step1 above (fetch data)
4. Continue until valid data found

Putting an observable in a for loop fires the observable multiple times immediately. This is a bad approach. What's a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables have a [retry](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) method which you can use by throwing an error as long as the data is not valid:

```js
let src: Observable<any>;// the source Observable
src.map(data => {
  if (!validate(data)) {
     throw "Invalid data";
  }
  return data;
})
.retry() // you can limit the number of retries
.subscribe(data => {
   // Do something with the data
});
```

you can use [retryWhen](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) if you need to check the error:

```js
let src: Observable<any>;// the source Observable
src.map(data => {
  if (!validate(data)) {
     throw "Invalid data";
  }
  return data;
})
.retryWhen(errors => errors.map(err => {
   if (err != "Invalid data") {
    throw err;
   }
 })
.subscribe(data => {
   // Do something with the data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use recursive function calls.

Fetching function:

```js
public getData(): Observable<any> {}
```

Usage:

```js
public refresh() {
   this.yourService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      // validate data !
      if (dataValid(data) {
         // do something cool here .. !
      }
      else {
         this.refresh(); // do it again ..
      }
   });
}
```